# How to force parameter to WiX MSI /norestart

Tags: wix

In WiX,
Is it possible to force using some flags like /NORESTART **with or without** using command line?

In other words, I want to create MSI package which always has /NORESTART flag applied, no matter is executed by double click or from CMD

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

As I know it's possible to set few InstallRunMode variables via custom actions.

```
session.SetMode(InstallRunMode.RebootNow, false);
session.SetMode(InstallRunMode.RebootAtEnd, false);
```

Update:
Also, it's possible to do it using bootstrapper application by passing /NORESTART to MsiPackage.

Comment: I guess we can do it natively without using CustomAction

Comment: I hoped so, but after few days of searching it was only way I found. Guess I should bookmark, maybe someone will share better one) P.S. Also check my update. It's not best idea, but in some cases it can help.

Comment: Thanks , I don't want to use bootstrapper in this case.